# Добавление сопрограммы из основного цикла событий

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, asyncio

Пытаюсь решить вопрос с асинхронной работой бота Вконтакте на питоне.
Не понимаю, как с помощью asyncio в *event loop* добавить событие из LongPooling, при этом продолжая опрос сервера:

```py
async def Schedule(self):
    await MessageSend()
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await MessageSend()


async def Listen():
    for event in Vk.LongPool.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.obj.text == 'Расписание':
                task = ioloop.create_task(Schedule())
            else:
                task = ioloop.create_task(MessageSend())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ioloop.create_task(Listen())
    ioloop.run_forever()
    ioloop.close()
```

В данном примере функции не запускаются, но если запускать созданную задачу через await, то все события игнорируются, пока не закончится выполнение Vk.Schedule()
Как устроить все таким образом, чтобы события из цикла продолжали поступать вместе с выполнением сопрограммы?

Comment: Вынеси `schedule` в отдельный тред, если не нужно блокировать main loop. `with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: task = loop.run_in_executor(executor,schedule)`

Comment: или Vk библиотеку перепишите на асинхронный хттпа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду вы используете vk_api?
Возможно лучше перейти на асинхронную библиотеку? Например [aiovk](https://github.com/Fahreeve/aiovk)

Или как вам предлагали выше – это вынести второй loop в отдельный поток/процесс. Но я думаю если пошла тема асинхронности, вам следует поменять библиотеку.

Comment: Спасибо, но после некоторых раздумий было решено использовать просто процессы вместо асинхронности. Не знаю, насколько верное это решение, но пока все работает

Comment: Нужно понимать специфику. Скорее всего ваша реализация потоков копирует в каждый процесс всю программу. Что очень неэффективно в случае, когда пользователей будет много. Таким образом в вашем случае все-таки лучше асинхронность использовать

Answer (score 0):

тут проблема в блокировке `Vk.LongPool.listen()` - этот цикл надо выполнять в отдельном треде или переделать на асинхронный. Таски запускаются в работу после следующего асинхронного вызова, а тут блок.